# adding all columns from mutiple tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple question.

I need to count all records from multiple tables with day and hour and add all of them together in a single final table.

So the query for each tab is something like this

select timestamp_trunc(timestamp,day) date, timestamp_trunc(timestamp,hour) hour, count(*) from `table_1`

select timestamp_trunc(timestamp,day) date, timestamp_trunc(timestamp,hour) hour, count(*) from `table_2`

select timestamp_trunc(timestamp,day) date, timestamp_trunc(timestamp,hour) hour, count(*) from `table_3`

and so on so forth

I would like to combine all the results showing number of total records for each day and hour from these tables.

Expected results will be like this

date, hour, number of records of table 1, number of records of table 2, number of records of table 3  ........

What would the most optimum SQL query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to `union` them together and aggregation:

```
select timestamp_trunc(timestamp, hour) as hh,
       countif(which = 1) as num_1,
       countif(which = 2) as num_2
from ((select timestamp, 1 as which
       from table_1
      ) union all
      (select timestamp, 2 as which
       from table_2
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) t
group hh
order by hh;
```

You are using `timestamp_trunc()`.  It returns a timestamp truncated to the hour -- there is no need to also include the date.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP, DAY) day, 
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP) hour, 
  COUNT(*) cnt,
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table
FROM `project.dataset.table_*`
GROUP BY day, hour, table
```

Comment: I think this is neat solution but only if the tables under the dataset are pretty much compatibles with each other and if we wanted select all tables in that dataset. In my case, some of them are not compatible like different partitioning  I only wanted to select some tables only, not the whole tables under the dataset. 
Any alternative solution?

Wildcard matched incompatible partitioning tables, first table table 1, first incompatible table table2.

Comment: still should work for you - you can add clause like `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN ('aaa', 'bbb' ...) so you can customize exact list of tables you want to collect data from

Comment: I was hoping this would work smoothly but apparently I stumbled into another issue.  I was using the prefix for the tables in the dataset such as site_*  and added the clause WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN ('ac_newyork', 'ac_Houston, bb_Dallas, bb_Chicago,  ...') 
but still got the message:

Wildcard matched incompatible partitioning tables, first aa_newyork, first incompatible table bb_LA.  


Is there any way out from this?   
I like this solution because it is simpler than the solution offered by @Gordon

Comment: It looks like it scans all tables in that dataset first and check if they are all with the same  partitioning before selecting which table to calculate.